# como hacer filtros con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Buenos días.
tengo el siguiente código, mi objetivo es mostrar únicamente las cédulas que tienen registro en la fecha solicitada, lo estoy intentando hacer con filtros de Jquery pero no lo e logrado, no se que estoy haciendo mal.
Agradecería mucho me ayudaran.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Control ingreso | Informes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dashboard.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="mendata" action="simulacion.json">
      <div class="datepick">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Desde:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_since"
                placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Hasta:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_until"
                placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--movement/hours-->
        <div class="button">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Mostrar Registros</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="container" class="container">
      <div class="hourcollaborate row">
        <div class="hourmen">
          <span>42:15:36</span>
        </div>
        <div class="collaborator">
          <span>156</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/dashboard.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  $(function () {//funcion para mostra el calendario
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true
      });
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
          useCurrent: false,
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          autoclose: true,
          todayBtn: true
      });
      $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      });
      $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
      });
  });

    $('#mendata').on('submit', function(event) {//evento del botón
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.hourmen').css('display','block');
      $('.collaborator').css('display','block');
      var url = $(this).attr('action');
      var payload = $(this).serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function(request) {
           request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+ token);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        data: payload,
        headers: {
          Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token,

        },
      })

      .done(function(response) {
        showRegister(response.data.list);
        showHours(response.data.hours);
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.token);
      })
      .fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .always(function(response) {
        console.log("complete");
      });
  });

  function showRegister(regis){
    //***********************--------------------*******************
    var since = $("#date_since").val();
    var until = $("#date_until").val();
    console.log(since);
    console.log(until);
  //***************---------------------***********-----------
    var html ="";
    for (var cc in regis) {
      //console.log(Object.keys(regis).length);//este me muestra cuantos trabajadores se registraron
      var cDate = Object.keys(regis[cc]).length;//este es para imprimir cuantos registros tiene la fecha
      //console.log(Object.keys(regis[cc]).length);
      if (regis.hasOwnProperty(cc)) {
        html += "<div class='panel panel-primary'>"+
                  "<div class='cc panel-heading'><a class='principal' href=#"+cc+"  data-toggle='collapse'>"+cc+
                    "</a><span class='badge'>"+cDate+"</span></div>";
        html += "<div class=' panel-body collapse' id="+cc+">"
        var i=0;//document.getElementById
        for (var date in regis[cc]) {
          if(date == since){
          var cReg = Object.keys(regis[cc][date]).length;
          if (regis[cc].hasOwnProperty(date)) {
            html += "<div class='panel panel-default'>"+
                      "<div class='panel-heading'><a href=#"+cc+"-"+i+" data-toggle='collapse'>"+date+
                        "</a><span class='badge'>"+cReg+"</span></div>";
            html += "<div class='panel-body collapse' id="+cc+"-"+i+" >hours";
            //console.log();
            for (var hour in regis[cc][date]) {
              if (regis[cc][date].hasOwnProperty(hour)) {
                html += "<div>"+ regis[cc][date][hour] +"</div>"
              }
            }
          }
          html += "</div>";
          html += "</div>";
          i++;
        }else {
          console.log("la fecha no coincide");
          var hola = $('a:not(.principal)');
          console.log(hola);
        }
        }
      }
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</div>";

    }
    $('#container').append(html);

    var collab = $(".collaborator > span");
    collab.html(showCollaborator());

    function showCollaborator(){
      var showcollab = 'Con  ' + Object.keys(regis).length + '  trabajadores';
      return showcollab;
    }

  }


  function showHours(hwork){
    for(var hours in hwork){
      if(hwork.hasOwnProperty(hours)){
        var man = $(".hourmen");
        var hourman = 'Horas trabajadas: ' + hwork;
        man.find('span').html(hourman);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Y EL ARCHIVO .JSON de donbde estoy tomando la información.

```
{
    "data": {
        "list": {
            "21082275": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:59:15"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:58:12"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:00:29"
                ]
            },
            "23324219": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:59"
                ]
            },
            "23754991": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:55:56",
                    "12:14:14"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:55:50"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:21"
                ]
            },
            "30024949": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:55:26",
                    "12:06:54"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:53:52"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:30"
                ]
            },
            "35353782": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:58:36"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:01:16"
                ]
            },
            "35520368": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "05:26:55"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "05:20:03"
                ]
            },
            "35522500": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "07:01:55"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:59:23"
                ]
            },
            "35523585": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:57:32"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:29"
                ]
            },
            "35523859": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:57:51",
                    "12:17:10"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:57:24",
                    "10:25:43"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:01:04"
                ]
            },
            "35523891": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:58:33"
                ]
            },
            "35528549": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:55:29"
                ]
            },
            "35531440": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:54:58",
                    "12:11:11"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:55:21"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:49:07"
                ]
            },
            "35533796": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "05:44:01"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "05:31:44"
                ]
            },
            "35534856": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "07:02:30"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:58:43"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:01:21"
                ]
            },
            "35535064": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "05:32:00"
                ]
            },
            "35535775": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:58:50"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:00:54"
                ]
            },
            "35537255": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:58:23"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:59:28"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:48:45"
                ]
            },
            "39808868": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:52:05"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:01:09"
                ]
            },
            "43091716": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:58:36"
                ]
            },
            "52034557": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:57:03"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:55:05"
                ]
            },
            "52655088": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:54:18",
                    "12:12:18"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:55:11"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:54:47"
                ]
            },
            "52734919": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "07:03:01"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:45"
                ]
            },
            "60259495": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:51:24"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:04"
                ]
            },
            "79126231": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "05:43:46",
                    "12:16:38"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "05:24:03"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "05:20:22"
                ]
            },
            "79966318": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:22:48"
                ]
            },
            "80656001": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:49:19"
                ]
            },
            "1070944702": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:54:42"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:54:08"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:48:59"
                ]
            },
            "1070952820": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "07:01:02"
                ]
            },
            "1070957262": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:53:56"
                ],
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:15"
                ]
            },
            "1070963126": {
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "11:36:34"
                ]
            },
            "1072592064": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:46:51",
                    "12:12:29"
                ]
            },
            "1079262385": {
                "2017-12-08": [
                    "06:54:06",
                    "07:24:20"
                ],
                "2017-12-09": [
                    "06:54:30"
                ]
            },
            "1087958411": {
                "2017-12-11": [
                    "06:59:32"
                ]
            }
        },
        "hours": "29:20:21"
    },
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTI5OTkxODAsImV4cCI6MTUxMjk5OTc4MCwidHlwZSI6ImltcGxpY2l0In0.jl3cjTTnzTbQhRKj8VRtgaJpLbl9U4pLJGND9ERwr1g"
}
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte de mejor manera, trata de reproducir tu código en un JsFiddle.

Comment: Reproducir este ejemplo es casi imposible.

Comment: mira aqui esta mi código en JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hxgtb8kj/

Comment: Podrias utilizar las funciones de filtrado y busqueda de Underscore.JS. Es completamente necesario realizar el filtrado en el lado del cliente? Cuando se trabaja con API JSON es recomendable relegar esa carga al servidor.

Comment: muchas gracias, buscare informacion sobre el tema